# How can I filter some touch events and let them pass from one view to another in Android?

Tags: android

I want to do either of the following.

1) Only allow swipe/fling on my view and disable single taps, long press and other events.

or

2) Overlay another view on top of my view and only allow swipe/fling/scroll events to pass through to the view below it.

Is it possible to do it in Android?

Comment: you may want to try Gesture detector class for that purpose.

Comment: right but how do I do it with GestureDetector?

Answer (score 0):

an Example of Using `GetureDetector`.

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnGestureListener {
    private GestureDetector gDetector;
    TextView ViewA;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    gDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
    ViewA = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtView);

}
 @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
    return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(me);
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    viewA.setText("-" + "DOWN" + "-");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    viewA.setText("-" + "FLING" + "-");
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    viewA.setText("-" + "LONG PRESS" + "-");
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    viewA.setText("-" + "SCROLL" + "-");
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
    viewA.setText("-" + "SHOW PRESS" + "-");
}    

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    viewA.setText("-" + "SINGLE TAP UP" + "-");
    return true;
}
```

}

here are the methods to use the touch event under the GestureDetector class. you can control each event.
hope that helped you.

Comment: Actually I know how to use the GestureDetector. I am not sure how to handle the case when one view is overlaid on top of another and how i can just filter out scroll/flings to reach the view below the top layer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a hacky solution which suffices for my case but it is a hack clearly. 
In onInterceptTouchEvent of the ViewGroup I eat all the MotionEvent.ACTION_UP if it was preceded by a MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN Event. By eat I mean I would return true from the function and an action cancel would be sent to the child view which got the initial down event and hence clicks would be ignored. However scrolls, flings etc work as expected.

A code sample if anybody is trying to do the same. Here lastMotionDown is a class level boolean variable.

```
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {

            if (this.lastMotionDown) {
                if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    this.lastMotionDown = true;
                    return false;
                }
                this.lastMotionDown = false;
                if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    //A click has happened prevent it.
                    return true;
                }
            }else {
                if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    this.lastMotionDown = true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            return false;
}
```